# Rails 4: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid with inconsistent behavior of update_all()

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have the two following methods in `class_controller` in my Rails 4-based app:

**checkout(),
checkin()**

The operations to the database these two methods perform are opposite: `checkout()` insert String value to the `checkout` field/column, while the `checkin()` removes the String value from the `checkout` field/column.

The code in both methods are quite similar:

```
def checkout
   @class = Class.where("id = ?", params[:class_id])
   @class.update_all(":checkout" => "done blah blah")
end

def checkin
   @class = Class.where("id = ?", params[:class_id])
   @class.update_all(":checkout" => "")  # set it empty or nil??
end
```

The call to checkout() mapped by a url works flawlessly, however, when the checkin() method throws the following error. Looks like the `update_all` method behaves inconsistently:

**PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column ":checkout" of relation "classes" does not exist LINE 1: UPDATE "classes" SET ":checkout" = '' WHERE (id = '1') ^ : UPDATE "classes" SET ":checkout" = '' WHERE (id = '1')**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised that you say the first version works. It should also fail, if there isn't a column named `:checkout`.

I would suggest to "fix" both versions to more common Ruby idioms:

```
def checkout
  @class = Class.where(id: params[:class_id])
  @class.update_all(checkout: 'done blah blah')
end

def checkin
  @class = Class.where(id: params[:class_id])
  @class.update_all(checkout: '')  # set it empty or nil?
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use either `"checkout"` or `:checkout` with `update_all`.

```
 @class.update_all(:checkout => "done blah blah")
```

[Symbols](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Symbol.html) in Ruby don't have to be quoted.